# Minimal code for a node diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I want to do a diagram like this:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#/media/File%3ADijkstra_Animation.gif

For a djikstras algorithm. Not looking to animate it in latex more a static image like this but with all the numbers on the lines etc...

I have managed to do one in tikz but the code is to large and difficult to manage. Is there another package out there that specifically allows me to draw node diagrams like this with a lot way less code so that’s is easier to manage and change the diagram?

**Code 1:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 24mm,
every state/.append style = {inner sep=0pt, fill=gray!10,
                             minimum size=7mm},
every edge/.style = {draw, -Triangle, bend angle=15},
                auto=right,
                        ]
\node (s1) [state,fill=gray!50]         {0};
\node (s2) [state, above right=of s1]   {2};
\node (s3) [state, right=of s2]         {$\infty$};
\node (s4) [state, below right=of s3]   {$\infty$};
\node (s5) [state, below  left=of s4]   {$\infty$};
\node (s6) [state, left=of s5]          {8};
%
\draw[gray!30, line width=5pt]
        (s1) to                     (s2)
        (s1) to [bend right=15]     (s6);
%
\draw   (s1) edge ["2"]             (s2)
        (s1) edge [bend right,"8"]  (s6)
        (s2) edge ["6"]             (s3)
        (s2) edge ["3"]             (s5)
        (s2) edge ["5"]             (s6)
        (s3) edge [out=135, in=90,looseness=1.5, "1"]  (s1)
        (s3) edge ["2"]             (s4)
        (s3) edge [bend right,"5"]  (s5)
        (s5) edge [bend right,"4"]  (s3)
        (s5) edge ["7"]             (s4)
        (s5) edge ["1"]             (s6)
        (s6) edge [bend right,"8"]  (s1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Code 2:**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Welcome to Overleaf --- just edit your LaTeX on the left,
% and we'll compile it for you on the right. If you open the
% 'Share' menu, you can invite other users to edit at the same
% time. See www.overleaf.com/learn for more info. Enjoy!
%
% Note: you can export the pdf to see the result at full
% resolution.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}


\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
:Title: Prim's algorithm
:Tags: Beamer, Layers, Foreach, Graphs
:Use page: 6


A step by step example of the `Prim's algorithm`_ for finding the `minimum
spanning tree`_. Animated using Beamer 
overlays.

.. _Prim's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm
.. _Minimum spanning tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree

| Source: Adapted from an example on Wikipedia_

.. _Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm
\end{comment}

% Declare layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Prim's algorithm}

%% Adjacency matrix of graph
%% \  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
%% a  x  7     5
%% b  7  x  8  9  7
%% c     8  x     5
%% d  5  9     x 15  6
%% e     7  5 15  x  8  9
%% f           6  8  x 11
%% g              9  11 x

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{selected vertex} = [vertex, fill=red!24]
\tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
\tikzstyle{weight} = [font=\small]
\tikzstyle{selected edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,red!50]
\tikzstyle{ignored edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,black!20]

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8, auto,swap]
    % Draw a 7,11 network
    % First we draw the vertices
    \foreach \pos/\name in {{(0,2)/a}, {(2,1)/b}, {(4,1)/c},
                            {(0,0)/d}, {(3,0)/e}, {(2,-1)/f}, {(4,-1)/g}}
        \node[vertex] (\name) at \pos {$\name$};
    % Connect vertices with edges and draw weights
    \foreach \source/ \dest /\weight in {b/a/7, c/b/8,d/a/5,d/b/9,
                                         e/b/7, e/c/5,e/d/15,
                                         f/d/6,f/e/8,
                                         g/e/9,g/f/11}
        \path[edge] (\source) -- node[weight] {$\weight$} (\dest);
    % Start animating the vertex and edge selection. 
    \foreach \vertex / \fr in {d/1,a/2,f/3,b/4,e/5,c/6,g/7}
        \path<\fr-> node[selected vertex] at (\vertex) {$\vertex$};
    % For convenience we use a background layer to highlight edges
    % This way we don't have to worry about the highlighting covering
    % weight labels. 
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \pause
        \foreach \source / \dest in {d/a,d/f,a/b,b/e,e/c,e/g}
            \path<+->[selected edge] (\source.center) -- (\dest.center);
        \foreach \source / \dest / \fr in {d/b/4,d/e/5,e/f/5,b/c/6,f/g/7}
            \path<\fr->[ignored edge] (\source.center) -- (\dest.center);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Code 3:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Introductory example
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {Intersection point};
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Points, lineas and curves
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle (2pt);
\draw (-2,-2) .. controls (0,0) .. (2,-2);
\draw (-2,2) .. controls (-1,0) and (1,0) .. (2,2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Circles and arcs
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](-1,0) circle (1.5);
\fill[blue!50] (2.5,0) ellipse (1.5 and 0.5);
\draw[ultra thick, ->] (6.5,0) arc (0:220:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Polygons
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue, very thick] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\draw[orange, ultra thick] (4,0) -- (6,0) -- (5.7,2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Diagram
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
roundnode/.style={circle, draw=green!60, fill=green!5, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick, minimum size=5mm},
]
%Nodes
\node[squarednode]      (maintopic)                              {2};
\node[roundnode]        (uppercircle)       [above=of maintopic] {1};
\node[squarednode]      (rightsquare)       [right=of maintopic] {3};
\node[roundnode]        (lowercircle)       [below=of maintopic] {4};

%Lines
\draw[->] (uppercircle.south) -- (maintopic.north);
\draw[->] (maintopic.east) -- (rightsquare.west);
\draw[->] (rightsquare.south) .. controls +(down:7mm) and +(right:7mm) .. (lowercircle.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%List of available colors 

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[black] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\filldraw[red] (3,0) rectangle (5,2);
\filldraw[green] (6,0) rectangle (8,2);
\filldraw[blue] (9,0) rectangle (11,2);
\filldraw[cyan] (1,-1) rectangle (3,-3);
\filldraw[magenta] (4,-1) rectangle (6,-3);
\filldraw[yellow] (7,-1) rectangle (9,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Different levels of thickness
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue, ultra thin] (-1,2) -- (1,-2);
\draw[blue, very thin] (0,2) -- (2,-2);
\draw[blue, thin] (1,2) -- (3,-2);
\draw[blue, thick] (2,2) -- (4,-2);
\draw[blue, very thick] (3,2) -- (5,-2);
\draw[blue, ultra thick] (4,2) -- (6,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not show the code you already have?

Comment: Because I wanted to use a different package other than tikz because I found the code to big and difficult to manage, so I did not want to focus on improving the code more finding a better easier package to use to specifically draw node diagrams. I will update my question though with all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately my `tkz-graph` package is currently "obsolete". It needs an update

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Dijkstra]
    \SetGraphUnit{4}
    \Vertices{square}{G,D,A,F}
    \WE(F){H}
    \EA(A){B}
    \EA(D){C}
    \NO(A){E}
    \Edge[label=$1$](H)(F)
    \Edge[label=$4$](G)(F)
    \Edge[label=$2$](H)(G)
    \Edge[label=$2$](G)(D)
    \Edge[label=$3$](D)(C)
    \Edge[label=$4$](F)(E)
    \Edge[label=$3$](A)(D)
    \Edge[label=$2$](A)(E)
    \Edge[label=$1$](A)(B)
    \Edge[label=$2$](A)(C)
    \Edge[label=$2$](C)(B)
    \Edge[label=$3$](E)(B)
    \SetUpEdge[lw=4pt,color=red]
    \Edges[style={opacity=.2}](H,F,E,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice that’s more what I was looking for. Does this have any issues with opening on other peoples pdf readers in respect of standalone class as I am still a bit confused by that.

Comment: @SomeT  No it's not a problem. The main problem is that I need some time to update the package and it's quite difficult at the moment.

Comment: I see 2.0 was released so I guess it happened in the meantime. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot tell you what the most efficient way to draw such diagrams is, but below might be a rather efficient way. The positions of the nodes are determined by the distances, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524297). (One distance was inconsistent in the drawing.) More importantly, you can use `overlay-beamer-styles` to make certain elements only visible on certain overlays.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, calc,bending,positioning, quotes,
overlay-beamer-styles}
\tikzset{gl/.style={green!60!black,draw,bend left=20,-{Stealth[bend]},visible on=<#1>},
gr/.style={green!60!black,draw,bend right=20,-{Stealth[bend]},visible on=<#1>},
    shortcut/.code={\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1/##1}}},
    third corner of triangle/.style={shortcut=triangle pars,
    triangle pars/.cd,#1,
    /tikz/insert path={
     let \p1=($(\pv{A})-(\pv{B})$),\n1={sqrt(pow(\x1/1cm,2)+pow(\y1/1cm,2))},
      \n2={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in
     (intersection cs:first line={(\pv{A})--($(\pv{A})+({\n2-cosinelaw(\n1,\pv{b},\pv{a})}:1)$)},
     second line={(\pv{B})--($(\pv{B})+({\n2+cosinelaw(\n1,\pv{a},\pv{b})}:1)$)})
    }},
  declare function={cosinelaw(\a,\b,\c)=acos((\a*\a+\b*\b-\c*\c)/(2*\a*\b));},
  triangle pars/.cd,
  A/.initial=A,B/.initial=B,a/.initial=2,b/.initial=2}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{An animated diagram}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 24mm,
every state/.append style = {inner sep=0pt, fill=gray!10,
                             minimum size=7mm},
every edge/.style = {draw}, auto=right]

 \path[scale=0.3] 
  node[state,label={[visible on=<2->]below left:a},
    alt=<3-5>{fill=yellow}{},
    alt=<6->{fill=red}{}](1){1}
  ++ (-15:7)  node[state,label={[blue,visible on=<3->]below:7},
    alt=<7->{fill=red}{}](2){2} 
  edge["7"] (1)
  [third corner of triangle={A=2,B=1,a=9,b=10}]
  node[state,label={[blue,visible on=<4->]above:9},alt=<8->{fill=red}{}
  ] (3){3}
  edge["9"] (1)
  edge["10"] (2)
  [third corner of triangle={A=2,B=3,a=11,b=15}] 
  node[state,alt=<8->{fill=red}{}] (4){4}
  edge["15"] (2)
  edge["11"] (3)
  [third corner of triangle={A=3,B=1,a=14,b=7}] 
  node[state,label={[blue,visible on=<5->]above:14}] (6){6}
  edge["14"] (1)
  edge["7"] (3)
  [third corner of triangle={A=4,B=6,a=9,b=6}]
    node[state,label={[visible on=<-2>]above right:b}
    ] (5){5}
  edge["6"] (4)
  edge["9"] (6)
  (1) edge[gr=3-] (2)
  (2) edge[gr=4-] (3); 
\end{tikzpicture}               
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is, of course, not an attempt to fully reproduce the animation you link to, but it provides you with the tools to get there. Note that you could also use a `standaloneframe` that comes with `\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}`.

**ADDENDUM**: A way to construct the diagram on the basis of the distances, as in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524297). It exploits that a triangle is unique (up to a sign choice) if you provide the lengths of the sides. So given two points and the length of the other two sides you can determine the third point (up to a sign).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, calc,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every state/.append style = {inner sep=0pt, fill=gray!10,
                             minimum size=7mm},
every edge/.style = {draw}, auto=right,
    shortcut/.code={\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1/##1}}},
    third corner of triangle/.style={shortcut=triangle pars,
    triangle pars/.cd,#1,
    /tikz/insert path={
     let \p1=($(\pv{A})-(\pv{B})$),\n1={sqrt(pow(\x1/1cm,2)+pow(\y1/1cm,2))},
      \n2={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in
     (intersection cs:first line={(\pv{A})--($(\pv{A})+({\n2-cosinelaw(\n1,\pv{b},\pv{a})}:1)$)},
     second line={(\pv{B})--($(\pv{B})+({\n2+cosinelaw(\n1,\pv{a},\pv{b})}:1)$)})
    }},
  declare function={cosinelaw(\a,\b,\c)=acos((\a*\a+\b*\b-\c*\c)/(2*\a*\b));},
  triangle pars/.cd,
  A/.initial=A,B/.initial=B,a/.initial=2,b/.initial=2]

 \path[scale=0.3] 
  node[state,label={below left:a}](1){1}
  ++ (-15:7)  node[state,label={[blue]below:7}](2){2} 
  edge["7"] (1)
  [third corner of triangle={A=2,B=1,a=9,b=10}]
  node[state,label={[blue]above:9}] (3){3}
  edge["9"] (1)
  edge["10"] (2)
  [third corner of triangle={A=2,B=3,a=11,b=15}] 
  node[state] (4){4}
  edge["15"] (2)
  edge["11"] (3)
  [third corner of triangle={A=3,B=1,a=14,b=7}] 
  node[state,label={[blue]above:14}] (6){6}
  edge["14"] (1)
  edge["7"] (3)
  [third corner of triangle={A=4,B=6,a=9,b=6}]
    node[state,label={above right:b}] (5){5}
  edge["6"] (4)
  edge["9"] (6); 
\end{tikzpicture}               
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is standalone frame? In the final frame as per above animation, how would you say  do that in tikz, you can't really embed an animation in a PDF as far as I am aware? So if you can explain to do that 'additionally', then I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @SomeT A `standaloneframe` is an environment that ships with `\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}`, it allows you to crop the animation, i.e. it is not a full beamer frame. The sentence "In the final frame as per above animation..." I do not understand. (You can embed animations in pdf, either with `beamer` or with the `animate` package. You can also create animated svgs with Ti*k*Z or some novel mechanisms by AlexG.)

Comment: But if I do that, then is the recipient able to see the animation in 'any' pdf reader software? Is it 100% embedded in the pdf, no external links etc....? I mean my goal was more for a static final image here more than anything. The animated one I just shown as example code, as it was pedantically asked for example code so I just randomly posted in all the code I currently have.

Comment: @SomeT No, pdf animations do not work for any viewer. Well, as you link to an animation I thought you wanted to create an animation, and my interpretation of "static" was that you get the next step by hitting the next page key, which is what the above code yields if you view the result in a pdf viewer. In any case, the above answer uses [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524297) in order to construct the diagram from the distances.

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution#2 in question description, just remove the animation part and paste it here for reference:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        vertex/.style={circle,opacity=.8,fill=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt},
        edge/.style={draw,thick,-,auto},
        weight/.style={font=\small},
    }
    % \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,opacity=1] (M) at (0,0){\includegraphics{a.png}};
    \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{
        % x={(M.south east)},y={(M.north west)},
        x=283,y=222,
    }
    % \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
    % \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    % 
    \foreach \pos/\name/\label in {
        (0.13,0.21)/1/0,
        (0.46,0.09)/2/$\infty$,
        (0.43,0.59)/3/$\infty$,
        (0.93,0.63)/4/$\infty$,
        (0.58,0.88)/5/$\infty$,
        (0.18,0.8)/6/$\infty$} {
        \node[vertex,label=\label] (\name) at \pos {$\name$};
    }
    % 
    \foreach \source/ \dest /\weight in {
        1/2/7, 
        1/3/9,
        1/6/14,
        2/4/15,
        2/3/10, 
        3/4/11,
        3/6/2,
        4/5/6,
        5/6/9} {
        \path[edge] (\source) -- node[weight] {$\weight$} (\dest);
    }
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can use reference picture to get exact node postion with remove the comment line and put reference picture there, then you can get the exact coordinate to fill in node position loop. then after everything done, just comment it out and use picture width/height as x/y to get final picture.

[image]